# GL_LINES is not visible inside a cube

Tags: jogl

What I would like to do is draw a parallelepiped (using GL_QUADS) and its edges (using GL_LINES).
The parallelepiped is supposed to be a Squash field, and the camera will be inside it.
The problem is when I use GL_LINES, the line drawn is not visible when the camera is inside the parallelepiped.

Couple of screenshots so you understand better :

Inside - Line not visible : https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZKy5.png

Outside - Line visible :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ah40O.png

This is what's inside my init method :

```
GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();      // get the OpenGL graphics context
      glu = new GLU();                         // get GL Utilities
      gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // set background (clear) color
      gl.glClearDepth(1.0f);      // set clear depth value to farthest
      gl.glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // enables depth testing
      gl.glEnable(GL_BLEND);
      gl.glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
      gl.glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);  // the type of depth test to do
      gl.glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST); // best perspective correction
      gl.glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH); // blends colors nicely, and smoothes out lighting
      gl.glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
```

and this is my display method :

```
GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();  // get the OpenGL 2 graphics context
  gl.glClearColor(0.55f, 0.55f, 0.55f, 1.0f);
  gl.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clear color and depth buffers
  gl.glLoadIdentity();  // reset the model-view matrix


  gl.glTranslated(-3.2, -2.82, -10); // translate into the screen

  gl.glBegin(GL_QUADS); // Start Drawing The Quad
  gl.glColor4ub(r,g,b, alpha);

  gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, 0);
  gl.glVertex3d(0, 5.640, 0);
  gl.glVertex3d(6.400, 5.640, 0);
  gl.glVertex3d(6.400, 0, 0);

  gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, 0);
  gl.glVertex3d(0, 5.640, 0);
  gl.glVertex3d(0, 5.640, 9.750);
  gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, 9.750);

  gl.glVertex3d(6.400, 0, 0);
  gl.glVertex3d(6.400, 5.640, 0);
  gl.glVertex3d(6.400, 5.640, 9.750);
  gl.glVertex3d(6.400, 0, 9.750);

  gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, 9.750);
  gl.glVertex3d(0, 5.640, 9.750);
  gl.glVertex3d(6.400, 5.640, 9.750);
  gl.glVertex3d(6.400, 0, 9.750);

  gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, 0);
  gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, 9.750);
  gl.glVertex3d(6.400, 0, 9.750);
  gl.glVertex3d(6.400, 0, 0);

  gl.glVertex3d(0, 5.640, 0);
  gl.glVertex3d(0, 5.640, 9.750);
  gl.glVertex3d(6.400, 5.640, 9.750);
  gl.glVertex3d(6.400, 5.640, 0);

  gl.glEnd(); // Done Drawing The Quad

  gl.glLineWidth(2);
  gl.glBegin(GL_LINES);
  gl.glColor4ub((byte)0,(byte)0,(byte)0, (byte)255);

  gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, 0);
  gl.glVertex3d(0, 5.640, 0);

  gl.glEnd();
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Lines are draw using the same z-buffer as quads. So when you are outside, lines are closer to camera than edges of quads and they are draw. When you are inside, surface of quads are closer and line is not draw. However because of numerical errors lines can appear or disappear from time to time. Turn of depth test and lines should always be draw.